# Answer transformed to comment?

Tags: support, comment, answers, deleted-answers

I wanted to answer a question, after I did my answer was automatically transformed to a comment. Why? I see another question here about this but they respond to the asker that this only happens when the answer is a link. My answer was not and it fully answered the question

Comment: Since this is an action by moderator, I suggest you ask [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/math-mods-office) or flag your comment.

Comment: Not providing a link to the Question or Comment/Answer at issue makes it something of a puzzle to find.  Sometimes (but not recently) when I see a post that seems either not intended as an Answer but as a Comment, or fails as an Answer and would work better as a Comment having some beneficial content, I will flag it for Moderator special attention and recommend that it be transferred to a Comment on the Question.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was not transformed *automatically*, instead it was done *manually* by a moderator. A moderator *can* do this for any answer (if it is longer than a comment it would get cut off).

Comment: Was it that bad?

Comment: I did not look into the content so far. I took your question as a technical one on the site mechanics.

Comment: On the content in specific case: First, that it was transformed to a cmnt also sends the message that  you did contribute something useful (otherwise it would have been just deleted, not preserved as a comment). So the feedback is not as negative as you might think it is. Would it also work as an answer? Likely, yes. But also note that such decisions might be taken based on the answer *in isolation* and the *style* of your answer is comment-like. Would you have written instead, say:  "Define your candidate for a norm functions as $d(x,0)$. Verify it is a norm." it's more clear it's an answer.

Comment: To make more clear the importance of style, let me give a still more risky example regarding style:  sometimes a user *answers* in the style of a rhetorical *question.* This can be fine in principle, but  when you review that in isolation and there you have the button: "This is a question posted as an answer."  it is *so* easy to get tripped up. Because you are shown  just the answer-post which is technically a question.